# Changing the background image of a div dynamically using dojo javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've been searching for a simple way to change the background image of a div using dojo. I'm sure it's simple enough, but I have been unable to find the right way to do it.

```js
var chartDiv = dojo.byId('idChart');
dojo.setStyle(chartDiv, 'background-image', url('http://static2.grsites.com/archive/textures/yello/yello001.jpg'));
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="idChart">
    <div style="float: left">
      <h3 style="color:DarkSlateGray;">Readmission Risk: <span id='idEstimatedRisk'>    </span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Using it this way doesn't change anything on the page, and I have not been able to find another way to do it using dojo.

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var chartDivNode = dojo.byId('idChart');
 dojo.setStyle(chartDivNode, 'backgroundImage', 'url(http://static2.grsites.com/archive/textures/yello/yello001.jpg)');
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="idChart" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="float: left">
      <h3 style="color:DarkSlateGray;">Readmission Risk: <span id='idEstimatedRisk'>100</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Will this work without specifying a width and height?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the effect you wish, I believe the primary problem in your own code was that you did not specify a width and height.  These are necessary to set the background image size.

I defined the HTML as follows:

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/query", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/ready"],
  function(parser, query, domStyle, ready) {
    ready(function() {
      var myNode = query("#idChart")[0];
      domStyle.set(myNode,
        "background-image",
        "url(http://static2.grsites.com/archive/textures/yello/yello001.jpg)");
    });
  }
);
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="idChart" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <div style="float: left">
      <h3 style="color:DarkSlateGray;">Readmission Risk: <span id='idEstimatedRisk'>100</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And this achieved the result you requested